# simple CSS attributes to HTML parser with java

Tags: java, html, css, regex, parsing

I was trying to parse the style attribute of a simple `<font>` tag and convert it back to simple html attributes. For instance, I have this string `<font style="font-family:tahoma;font-size:24px;color:#9900CC;">` and I'd like to somehow convert it to `<font size="24" color="#9900CC" face="tahoma">` I know this can be done with regex but I have no idea how?

thanks

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: Why would you not use a regex if you know how to do it with regex?

Comment: @JanDvorak Are you assuming `replaceAll` doesn't use regexes?

Comment: @melpomene `replaceAll` can take either a regex or a string. I was assuming the second interpretation (note "I know this can be done with regex but ...").

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm looking at [`java.lang.String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). I don't see a second version.

Comment: why would I need to do that? because I want to do that... please stick with the topic...

Comment: I think the question is: "I know you **can** do this with regular expressions, but I have no idea how to go about doing so. Can anyone provide me with direction?"

Comment: @RobinVanPersi unless you need it for academic purposes only or you explain / mention the reason, I'm going to stick to "It's a bad idea. Don't do that."

Comment: @melpomene Oops, sorry, I was thinking of javascript.

Comment: @JanDvorak - its for military purposes...

Comment: @RobinVanPersi Sorry, I don't buy it.

Comment: @JanDvorak - who cares whether you buy it or not. I'm not giving you any reason.. and I don't need your help after all..

Comment: @RobinVanPersi It's up to you to not explain. Please don't feel offended by my decision to comment this as a bad choice.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done with a single regex anyway. You'd need to use some sort of hash table to look up each HTML attribute, since some of them differ in name from their respective CSS property (e.g. "size" is an HTML attribute, while it's "font-size" in CSS). Either way, it's a pretty terrible idea.

Comment: @JanDvorak - your comments are a waste of time and space...

Comment: @sgroves - I've already found a solution for that. wither its a terrible idea or not I have to do it like that because it doesn't work properly with android's TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("blabla"), BufferType.SPANNABLE) function

Comment: "because it doesn't work properly with ..." now that's an explanation I wanted to hear. Please don't feel offended by my desire to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the simplest solution I've made so far its a dirty solution but it works like a charm:

```
static public String convertCSSFonttoHTML(String css)
{

    List<List<String>> allFontTags = regexFindMultiStrings("<font[^>]*(style=['\"][^'\"]+['\"])[^>]*>", css);
    String allAttributes = "";

    for(int y=0; y<allFontTags.size(); y++)
    {
        String style = allFontTags.get(y).get(0);
        String size = regexFindString("font-size:([^0-9]+)", style);
        String color = regexFindString("color:([^;]+);", style);
        String face = regexFindString("font-family:([^;]+)", style);

        if(!size.isEmpty())
             allAttributes += "size=\""+size+"\" ";

        if(!color.isEmpty())
             allAttributes += "color=\"" + color + "\" ";

        if(!size.isEmpty())
             allAttributes += "face=\""+face+"\"";



        //do replacements to the first occurance
        css = css.replaceFirst(style, allAttributes);

        //empty atts
        allAttributes = "";
    }

    //Log.e("Regex", css);


    return css;

}
```